# HttpException does not interrupt dependencies flow in FastAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I have dependencies flow in my endpoint.

```
    @router.post("/configure_something", dependencies=[Depends(validate_token_model), Depends(get_user_by_token)])
    def configure_resource(request: Request):
    """ do something
        """
    return request.state.token
```

In first dependency I want to validate user token using pydantic model.

```
def validate_token_model(request: Request, token: str = Header(...)):
    """
    Get user token from request Header.
    Update context var request with user token.
    Return 400 if token validation exception failed.
    """

    # validate token model
    try:
        TokenModel(token=token)
        # update context var

    except RequestValidationError as error:
        # return 400
        logger.info(f'Token validation failed. Token:{token}. Error:{error}')
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Incorrect token format")
    except Exception as error:
        logger.critical(f'Token validation failed. Token:{token}. Error:{error}')
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Token validation failed.")
    request.state.token = token
```

The problem is when validation failed - raise HTTPException does not interrupt dependencies flow, and I see that second dependency is executed.

```
def get_user_by_token(request: Request):
    """
    Get User object from request context var.
    Update context var request with User object.
    Return 500 if something went wrong.
    Return 400 if user not exists.
    """
    try:
        user = some_storage.get(token=request.state.token)
    except Exception as error:
        # return 404
        logger.warning(f'Failed to get user. Error:{error}')
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Internal server error.")
    # if token is correct get user from RoleModel
    if user is None:
        logger.warning(f'User by token:{request.state.token} not exists')
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f"User by token:{request.state.token} not exist. Login first")
    # update context var
    request.state.user = user
```

If I remove get_user_by_token dependency from the flow it raises http exception correctly. How can I interrupt dependency flow is HTTPException was raised in first dependency?

Comment: Are you sure that FastAPI resolves the dependencies from the start of the list? Since `get_user_by_token` depends on `validate_token` being run, it should intead depend on that function instead of having them as separate dependencies in the `dependencies` decorator.

Comment: @MatsLindh The main idea here is that you use dependencies in chain and every dependency write to context manager if not fails.

Comment: Yes, I understand that - but the `get_user_by_token` dependency _depends_ on `validate_token` having run. So it should have a `Depends` on that dependency instead of you having to magically call `validate_token` before `get_user_by_token` gets called (and thus, it shouldn't have a temporal coupling to how `request.state` gets set up). Dependency results are cached, so it's generally not expensive to refer to the dependency every time you need the results from one.